# nestjs @SubscribeMessage UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.contextUtils.getContextFactory is not a function

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs

I am seeing this error in my nestjs application

(node:16561) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.contextUtils.getContextFactory is not a function
    at WsContextCreator.getMetadata (/Users/sajankumarvijayan/Documents/projects/review.io/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-context-creator.js:73:50)
    at WsContextCreator.create (/Users/sajankumarvijayan/Documents/projects/review.io/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-context-creator.js:28:68)

Here is my example code:

```
import {
   SubscribeMessage,
   WebSocketGateway,
   WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server } from 'ws';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class SocketGateway {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage('event')
  onEvent(client: any, data: any): void {
    this.server.emit('update');
  }
}
```

If i remove the @SubscribeMessage annotation the error is gone. I think this exception is not handled but looking for some answers and help to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same issue and it disappeared after I upgraded `@nestjs/core` and `@nestjs/common` to `7.x.x` versions

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me and in my case was a version issue, I was using version 6.x of packages **@nestjs/common** and **@nestjs/core**.

It got fixed after I made a major upgrade in those libraries. Since I didn't have any version restriction, I've performed a full major version upgrade. Following instructions for **npm**

One step

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates && ncu -u && npm i
```

Or breaking it down...

Install check updates in case you don't have it yet

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Gives you the list

```
ncu -u
```

Install

```
npm install
```

This will also update your **package.json** file

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same error, updating dependency versions through the `npm-check-updates` helped

`ncu -u`

`npm install`

Answer (score 2):

I figured the issue was the version I fixed by running `yarn upgrade --scope @nestjs --latest` does the magic.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Wich version are you using now?

Comment: maybe try yarn upgrade --latest I am using 7.0.1

Comment: Thanks, my issue was that I use `6.x.x` version of `@nestjs/core` and `@nestjs/common` with `@nestjs/microservices` version `7.0.2`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. To resolve it i updated `nestjs` with `nest update -f -t latest`, for some reason the `-f` flag was necessary for me, otherwise it wasn't updating.